# Forcing in Constructive Set Theories

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, intuitionism

I searched on the internet, but I could not find anything useful about applications of forcing in constructive set theories.
Are there any developments of forcing in CZF or IZF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think John L Bell introduces at the end of *Set theory - Boolean Valued models and independence proofs* a sort of forcing theory in IZF, where instead of creating a Boolean valued model, one creates a Heyting-valued model. You may want to take a look at it

Comment: I think that most of the forcing in constructive settings is done via toposes and whatnot in a more categorical setting. I know that David Roberts has done some work on the topic. Not sure if you'll find it useful or not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Actually I could not find anything at all by searching subjects like forcing in constructive set theory. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See

[Forcing for IZF in sheaf toposes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228380851_Forcing_for_IZF_in_sheaf_toposes)

Also

[Toposes from Forcing for Intuitionistic ZF with Atoms.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.03399)

---

Edit:

Maybe more references:

[Heyting-valued models for intuitionistic set theory](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0061825)

The book "Intuitionistic logic, model theory and forcing" by Fitting.

see also the following web-page where some references are also given:

[Constructive Set Theory: Forcing, Large Sets, and Mathematics](https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=0301162)

[Topological forcing semantics with settling](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007211001369?via%3Dihub).

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any work using Kripke models instead of toposes?

Comment: In Gambino's thesis he does sheaf interpretation in two steps: first for presheaves and then for a local operator, so the first step is like Kripke models. It is not very topos-theoretic. The work is also interesting as it works for CZF. http://www.cs.le.ac.uk/people/ngambino/Publications/thesis.pdf

Comment: @UlrikBuchholtz: Thank you very much for the link.

Comment: @ErfanKhaniki It may be a too late answer, but works by [Robert Lubarsky](http://www.math.fau.edu/people/faculty/lubarsky.php) heavily use a (variant of) Kripke model.

Comment: @HanulJeon, thanks a lot for the comment.